# I installed pytorch lighing but when I run the code it gives mistake. How can I solve this one?

Tags: python-3.8, pytorch-lightning, pytorch-geometric

> File "train.py", line 3, in 
>     import pytorch_lightning as pl
> File "/root/miniconda3/envs/mmTrans/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/**init**.py", line 20, in 
>     from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import Callback  # noqa: E402
> File "/root/miniconda3/envs/mmTrans/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/callbacks/__init__.py", line 14, in 
>     from pytorch_lightning.callbacks.base import Callback
> File "/root/miniconda3/envs/mmTrans/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/callbacks/base.py", line 26, in 
>     from pytorch_lightning.utilities.types import STEP_OUTPUT
> File "/root/miniconda3/envs/mmTrans/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/utilities/__init__.py", line 18, in 
>     from pytorch_lightning.utilities.apply_func import move_data_to_device  # noqa: F401
> File "/root/miniconda3/envs/mmTrans/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/utilities/apply_func.py", line 26, in 
>     from pytorch_lightning.utilities.imports import _compare_version, _TORCHTEXT_AVAILABLE
> File "/root/miniconda3/envs/mmTrans/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/utilities/imports.py", line 25, in 
>     from packaging.version import Version
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packaging'

I want to train the model for argovere and I installed all requirements to my linux, I checked packaging model is here but still gives mistake.

How can I solve this one?

Comment: Can't you jus pip install packaging..

Comment: How did you come to know *all requirements*?